# How to get DirectoryInfo and/or FileInfo of specifiek directories?

Tags: c#, .net, subdirectory, directoryinfo

For an exercise I have to put the path of all the directories on my I:\ disk, the amount of files in those directories (and in their subfolders) and the size of the directory
in a CSV-file.
I've been able to write small pieces of code that give me a part of the solution.

With this code I'm able to get all the names of the directories.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string importPath = string.Empty;
    importPath = @"I:\";

    foreach (string directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(importPath, "*.*",     SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(directory);
    }
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And with this code I get all the info that I need to put in the CSV-file, but only from the I:\ disk and not it's directories.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string importPath = string.Empty;
    importPath = @"I:\";

    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(importPath);
    double sizeOfDir = DirectorySize(dInfo, true);

    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(importPath);
    FileInfo[] f = d.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    System.Console.WriteLine(dInfo.FullName + "; " + f.Length.ToString() + "; " +
            string.Format("{0:0.00}", ((double)sizeOfDir) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) + "GB");
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}

private static double DirectorySize(DirectoryInfo dInfo, bool includeSubDir)
{
    double totalSize = dInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                 .Sum(file => file.Length);
    if (includeSubDir)
    {
        totalSize += dInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                 .Sum(dir => DirectorySize(dir, true));
    }
    return totalSize;
}
```

I don't know how I can combine these 2 or if I have to do something totally different.
An example of what I should get in the end is:

```
I:\Scanner; 1543; 100GB
I:\Printer; 296; 22GB
I:\SysDeploy; 935; 66GB
I:\Intern; 4256; 30GB
```

Comment: If you only need to know the folders directly in I:\ you could simply loop all of the directories.

Comment: your teacher wants to see `recursive functions`, i guess? I.e. every dir in `I:`, then all in `I:\whatever` .. `I:\whatever\andSoOn`

Comment: If you need to show some sort of progress or only want to go n levels deep then a recursive function is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Use `Directory.GetDirectories` to get all directories including sub directories

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-7.0

```
 string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"i:\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You can then loop through the paths getting the DirectoryInfo for each directory:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
```

However be carfull running this on the root of a big drive (e.g. c:\) as this could take a while.